# Cut and paste the array elements in most efficient way

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, algorithm, mongodb

I know that `$pull` and `$push` can be used to update array elements in mongodb. 
However I want to cut the element and paste it to other index. 
What I'm trying to say is this;

**Example1**

Let's assume I have

```
var arr = [a , b, c, d, e];
```

I want to take element e and place it at index 0. Now it should be

```
var arr  = [e, a , b, c, d];
```

What are the changes;

```
Indices of (a b c d) increase by 1.
```

**Example2**

Let's assume I have

```
var arr = [a , b, c, d, e];
```

I want to cut element b and paste it at index 3. Now it should be

```
var arr  = [a , c, d, b, e];
```

What are the changes;

```
Indices of (c d) decrease by 1.
```

How can I handle it in a most efficient way? Take the subarray that store it, then recreate the arr array?

I want to do it with less amount of code with best efficient way. I don't know the tricks of mongodb.  I checked [the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update-array/) but couldn't find the best solution for this. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for part one:

```
var arr  = [a , b, c, d, e];

var item = arr.slice(2,1);

arr.push(item);
```

for part two:

```
var arr = [a , b, c, d, e];

  var items = arr.slice(2,2);

  arr.splice(4,0,items[0], items[1]);
```

Comment: thank you but these were just examples, the indices will be dynamic.

Comment: you don't have to hard code the parameter values in

Answer (score 0):

To limit change to specific indexes I believe you might be looking for [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/#up._S_slice)

Answer (score 0):

Given the document,

```
> db.history.find({})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e02e2c319d15b8fd9c6e69"), "arr" : ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e" ] }
```

With the following two commands, cut or take element from array through `$pull`, then past or place it through `$push` and [`$position`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/position/)

```
> db.history.update({}, {$pull: {arr: 'e'}})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
> db.history.update({}, {$push: {arr: {$each: ['e'], $position: 0}}})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

Result

```
> db.history.find({})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e02e2c319d15b8fd9c6e69"), "arr" : [ "e", "a", "b", "c", "d" ] }
```

Same logic for your second example

```
> db.history.update({}, {$pull: {arr: 'b'}})
> db.history.update({}, {$push: {arr: {$each: ['b'], $position: 3}}});
```